# Vue.js Component registration template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Here a very simple component

```
const MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
   data () {
      // data here...
   },
   methods: {
      // methods here...
   },
   template: '<p>Hello, world !!!</p>'
});
```

Is it a way to use a external file to write html code `<p>Hello, world!</p>` instead of the string template ?

I know it is a way with single file components (https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/single-file-component.html).

But unfortunately, i can't follow this way because in my context, i can't use tools like Vue CLI for example

Comment: [7 Ways to Define a Component Template in Vue.js](https://dzone.com/articles/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs)

Comment: Thank you, very informative to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `template` in your example can be sourced from anywhere. So its possible to do:

template.js:

```
export default {
  return "<p>Hello, world!!!</p>"
}
```

component.js

```
import template from 'template'

const MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: template,
});
```